# iPhone 6/6+ optimization issue

Tags: ios, optimization, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I spent a lot of time trying optimize my app for iPhone6/6+, but several UI elements have not yet been obtained to optimize.

1. UINavigationBar & UISearchBar with custom image background **[SOLVED]**:

[image]

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar"]       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

UISearchBar's background was set in storyboard.

There is ImageSet for UINavigationBar and UISearchBar which contains 1x, 2x, and 3x png files.

2. UITableViewCell: **[SOLVED]**

[image]

**cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        UISegmentedControl *mapTypeSelect = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]
                                             initWithItems:
                                             [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                NSLocalizedString(@"MAP_STANDART", nil),
                                                NSLocalizedString(@"MAP_HYBRID", nil),
                                                NSLocalizedString(@"MAP_SATELLITE", nil),
                                                nil]];

        CGSize cF = cell.frame.size;
        [mapTypeSelect setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, cF.width-20, cF.height-10)];
```

3. UISearchDisplayController position (1 - search activated; 2 - search began):

[image]
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: #2: You are setting a frame for the `UISegmentedControl`. An adaptive UI that works for an iPhone 4S, 5/5S, 6 and 6+ will need to use constraints/autolayout. A better method would be a Storyboard cell / xib cell (with constraints) rather than generating the cell in code but you could add the constraints in code if you prefer.

Comment: @RoboticCat: Thank you! My inattention - in another class I did exactly as you wrote ))  Do you have any solution for #1 and #3?

Comment: Absolutely no idea for #1 or #3.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for question #1 from [iOS 8 NavigationBar BackgroundImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052454/ios-8-navigationbar-backgroundimage)

**EDITED after @RoboticCat answer**

```
UIEdgeInsets stretchablePart = { .left = 0, .right = 50, .top = 0, .bottom = 0 };
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:stretchablePart resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

where **navBar** is Imageset of 1x,2x and 3x images

Comment: Wouldn't you want the cap insets to cover the bubbles so that only the middle is stretched?