# UINavigatoinBar background image appearing twice swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set a background image for UINavigationBar. I have done it many times in Objective-C but in swift, I am facing a problem. I have searched and tried many things but none did work for me.

Here is the code I am using:

```
let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "header")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, for: .default)
```

My header image has following dimensions:

375 × 64 for 1x and so on for 2x and 3x. I have tried with 320x64 as well, but still, it doesn't work.

Screenshot:

[image]
As you can see, the image is appearing twice and not covering complete width.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

After trying

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "header")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```

[image]
Still appearing twice.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052454/ios-8-navigationbar-backgroundimage

Comment: I don't see any problem in above way of setting background image to the navigation bar. Internally the image should be stretched and displayed accordingly. Why don't you try setting some other image as it could be some issue with the image you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

**Swift**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "header")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```

**Objective C**

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"header"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeStretch] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: I tried it but still, nav bar image appears twice like the screenshot.

Comment: did you removed your previous code cause there are two images in the screen shot

Comment: yeah, my code is being called only once and this is the only place where i am setting background image.

Answer (score 0):

Try print something or use debug point to sure that your code not called twice, or use

```
let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "header")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch)
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, for: .default)
```

Answer (score 0):

First add this line in your appDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsMethod`

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.clear
```

Then add the following in `viewDidLoad` method

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "header") {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(image.resizableImage(withCapInsets:UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
            UINavigationBar.appearance().contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
}
```

Comment: it doesn't even set background image. Only white nav bar

Comment: can you show me the code? , because it works perfectly for me,

Comment: in viewDidLoad method

Comment: @iBug please check my updated answer if you have not yet solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use a debug point to make sure the code does not run twice, then:

```
let navBackgroundImage = UIImage(named: "header")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch)
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, for: .default)
```